# JMS Serializer Bundle: Getting a list of all Entites with * @ExclusionPolicy("ALL")

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am at the process of filtering the doctrine entites, with `ExclusionPolicy(All)`...

Is there a method call I can use, to get a list of all entites (in a project or a bundle), where the exclusionPolicy annotation is activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways that you can exclude values from serialization.  In your case, I think the best option would be to [Create different views of your object](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies#creating-different-views-of-your-objects)

Straight from the docs that I linked to, do something like this:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

class BlogPost
{
    /** @Groups({"list", "details"}) */
    private $id;

    /** @Groups({"list", "details"}) */
    private $title;

    /** @Groups({"list"}) */
    private $nbComments;

    /** @Groups({"details"}) */
    private $comments;
}
```

I'm not sure what you are serializing for, but if you are using FOSRestBundle and are serializing your response, all you need to do to only serialize a specific group is something like this:

```
$view = $this->view($data, 200);
$view->setSerializationContext(
    SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('list'))
);
return $this->handleView($view);
```

with this configuration, the `$comments` will not be included.  So this way, you can exclude whatever properties you want just by defining the Group that you have defined.

If you aren't using FOSRestBundle, you can set the group as it mentions in the docs:

```
use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;

$serializer->serialize(
    new BlogPost(), 
    'json', 
    SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('list'))
);
```